# Not getting the desired output when using the Python list

Tags: python-3.x, list

When I run this code, output is **11**, but my expected output is **10**.

```
a=[10]
b=a
b[0]=11
print(a)
```

What's the issue? And how do I get my expected output without importing any external module?

Comment: By `b=a` you're telling Python that `b` should reference `a`, i.e. that they are two different names for the same list. So any changes to `b` will change `a`, because they're the same. If you wanted two different list, then you need to copy it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @TedKleinBergman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `b` is a reference to `a`. Changing any element of `a` or `b` are affecting the whole `a` and `b` list. To keep the list `a` always the same, Copy `a` to `b` then changing won't affect to `a`.

```
a = [10]
b = a.copy() # Also can slice it by b = a[:]
b[0] = 11
print(a)
```